# Japanese and Russian characters - web encoding?

Tags: php, python, character-encoding

I have a Zope/Plone WS that calls some functions written in Python.
That WS are called by PHP pages (utf-8 into header) but characters aren't visible.

I've tried to decode (where possible) special chars into entities (into Python) and that works, but not all chars have corresponding HTML entities.

I've tried to save the original Python file in UTF-8 format, but I thought that wasn't the right way.

Can someone help?

*note* : I pass through some `php include`, if this could be an hint...

**Edit** it's weird, because if I log all the "pieces" singly, then I have the right chars encoded. If I go up to the "main php page" (where I include all pieces), that messes up everything.

Obviously, the "main php page" has that:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What is calling what how exactly, where are the characters screwing up(?)/disappearing(?), what do you get and don't you get where? And BTW, every Unicode character has an HTML entity, if only a numeric one.

Comment: @deceze : ok, but I can't substitue every single char with a number. It would be crazy. BTW, the chars screwing are characters like (é,è,ì and jappanese and russian chars).

Comment: All languages have a function that will encode your strings as HTML entities. I hope you haven't been doing this by hand? And well, yes, at some point you're handling encodings incorrectly, that's why your characters are screwing up. Without more information it's impossible to say where exactly that is.

Comment: @deceze : I suppose that chars are screwed between WS and PHP communication. That's because onto server (with debug) all it's fine. Onto client side, even if I had utf-8 spec. in the header, all messes up. Any idea ?

Comment: Please show some code. Show some data. Show some expected data, show some screwed up data. [Read a bunch of articles I wrote about encodings](http://kunststube.net).

Comment: @deceze : into client side, I have that: `init_message=Ins<E9>rer date d<92>arriv<E9>e et de d<E9>part` . Onto server side, I have: `'init_message': u'Ins\xe9rer date d\x92arriv\xe9e et de d\xe9part'`

Comment: How does the text transform from `\xe9` into `<E9>`? And are you possibly outputting this `<E9>` directly into HTML, which causes the browser to interpret `<E9>` as an invalid tag, thus "hiding" it?

Comment: @deceze : I dind't told you the truth. If I open my log with "less" I saw that, but if I open with tail, it encode in the right way. So, the problem must be elsewhere

Comment: Please just show a string as you would expect it and a `bin2hex($str)` of how you're actually receiving it.

Comment: @deceze : this is what I obtain: 496e73e972657220646174652064926172726976e9652065742064652064e970617274 and i want to have following string: "Insérer date darrivée et de départ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited the file `site.py` of python.
I follow that guide: [click here](http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html) and everything is ok now.
Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 2):

> 496e73e972657220646174652064926172726976e9652065742064652064e970617274

That string is encoded in ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8.

Somewhere you're converting your strings to ISO-8859-1, which means they're not interpreted correctly when trying to interpret them as UTF-8, and all non-European characters will be discarded since ISO-8859-1 can't encode anything but a handful of European characters.

Comment: I dind't do any conversion. My string start as unicode and isn't ever converted. So, it's a php or apache matter?

Comment: I don't know because you have not given any details or shown any code! The fact is that string is not UTF-8. Try to figure out at which point exactly it's not UTF-8 first.

Comment: I dind't give any line of code, because is a complex code: WS,PHP and PYTHON are involved. I told you everything and the scenario is exactly that what I previously described. I thank you for helping me, but i can't provide any line of code, or I have to share entire project.